# print device configuration page programmatically under windows

Tags: c#, c++, printing

I'm trying to get the total pages count from all the printers connected to a computer. To do that i try in different ways but nothing give me the expected result:

- *SNMP:* Very useful but impossible use it on a local printer.
- *Win32_printer:* No way to get the total page count of a network printer and more of the local printers not store the page count on it.
- *printui.dll:* total page count not supported.

Now i'm trying a different approach: there is a way to programmatically print the device configuration page (Example: [THAT](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf-JAVA/Doc/images/176/c02007084.gif)) to a file? you can print it whitout connect the printer to a PC's so it shoud be stored somewhere in some digital format. the only thing i found on internet is the Bidi Communication but i can't found any documentation that can help me... I not need a particular programming language, but if possible i prefere c#,c++ or java.

**@Soner Gönül:** Ok, so i choose c# just because is the language that i use to write the snmp test, but examples in other languages are appreciated:

*SNMP:*

```
SNMP snmp = new SNMP();
// Aprire la connessione verso la stampante
try
{
   snmp.Open(IPAddressOfPrinter, CommunityString, Retries, TimeoutInMS);
} catch {
MessageBox.Show("Unable to reach the printer");
}
//Sides Counter
lblSides.Text = snmp.Get(".1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.4.1.1").ToString();
rtbLog.Text += "Printer Counter: " + lblSides.Text;
rtbLog.Text += " Sides.\n";
```

That code give me the number of sides printed by the printer, that is ok, but need that the printer is a network printer, on a USB printer i can't use SNMP.

*Win32_Printer:*

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + System.Environment.MachineName.ToString() + @"\root\cimv2"); //yeah... i know @"root\cimv2" is enought, i notice only now...
    scope.Connect();
    ObjectQuery PRNquery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");
    ManagementObjectSearcher PRNsearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, PRNquery);
    ManagementObjectCollection PRNqueryCollection = PRNsearcher.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject m in PRNqueryCollection)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(m["JobCountSinceLastReset"].Tostring());
       //But the result is Zero or random error the 90% of the times.

    }
```

*priuntui.dll:*

If i launch

```
rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /something
```

or try to export the report with:

```
public static class PrintTest
{
    [DllImport("printui.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern void PrintUIEntryW(IntPtr hwnd,
        IntPtr hinst, string lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
    public static void Print(string printerName)
    {
        var printParams = string.Format(@"/f C:\test.dat /Xg /n{0}", printerName);
        PrintUIEntryW(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, printParams, 0);
    }
}
```

i not found a page count report, but only generic information.

Comment: Please choose one specific language and show what have you tried to solve your problem first..

Comment: I edit the main post with more information, thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey buddy were you able to save the configuration page of the printer to pdf file ?